# Gmail API - ListUsersLabels - No messagesTotal

Tags: php, gmail-api

I'm using the GMail API to retrieve my labels:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/list

My code is as follows:

```
$userId = 'me';

$labels = array();

try {
    $labelsResponse = $service->users_labels->listUsersLabels($userId);

    if ($labelsResponse->getLabels()) {
        $labels = array_merge($labels, $labelsResponse->getLabels());
    }

    foreach ($labels as $label) {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($label);
        echo "</pre>";
    }
} catch (Excetion $e) {
    print 'An error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

This all generally seems to work however it never returns the total number of messages within the label:

```
Google_Service_Gmail_Label Object
(
    [colorType:protected] => Google_Service_Gmail_LabelColor
    [colorDataType:protected] => 
    [id] => INBOX
    [labelListVisibility] => labelShow
    [messageListVisibility] => hide
    [messagesTotal] => 
    [messagesUnread] => 
    [name] => INBOX
    [threadsTotal] => 
    [threadsUnread] => 
    [type] => system
    [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [modelData:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [processed:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Does anyone know why this would be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the Label Id to get the number of messages attached to it. First execute the [List](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/list?apix=true#try-it) function to get all the labels, then take the Id of the label you need and use it in the [Get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/get?apix_params=%7B%22userId%22%3A%22me%22%2C%22id%22%3A%22Label_9026608408141358353%22%7D#try-it) function.

In my case this returns:

```
{
 "id": "Label_ID",
 "name": "labelName",
 "type": "user",
 "messagesTotal": 11,
 "messagesUnread": 0,
 "threadsTotal": 11,
 "threadsUnread": 0
}
```

Another way is doing a search query, store the message IDs in an array, and get the length:

```
def get_emails():
        user_id = 'me' #Your email
        mail_ids = []
        query = 'label:your_label' 
        response = mail_service.users().messages().list(userId=user_id, q=query).execute()
        items = response.get('messages', [])
        if not items:
                print('No mails found')
                sys.exit()
        else:
                for items in items:
                        mail_ids.append(items['id'])
        print(len(mail_ids))
```